# Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In an attempt to stream line some processes I have attempted to create a script to move a paper process into a google form. I've nhever really tinkered with Javascript but I have been following the trail of errors down to this one which I cannot seem to shake.

Currently I'm trying to define the range of data but keep getting the error mentioned in the title. Am I incorrectly calling the sheet in the script? I cannot seem to figure out how to properly define them.

Below is the section that defines the variables and sheets. Anything I'm doing incorrectly?

```
 function sendEmail() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()[0];
  var startRow = 2;  
  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 12;   
  // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12)
  //Assigning spreadsheet feilds
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
 var firstName = row[1];
 var guestFirstN = row[6]; 
 var guestLastN = row[7];
 var arrivalDate = row[8];
 var numberNights = row[9];
 var rmName = row[10];
 var rmAgree = row[11];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to define the Sheet you want to get the data from since a Spreadsheet can have multiple Sheets.
Try replacing

```
var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12)
```

with
`var dataRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12);`

Comment: I've added this however it has generated at Cannot find method getRange((class),number,(class),number) error. I've searched around and am sort of confused as to why the error is generated as startRow and numRows is defined below. 

I've inserted the suggestion as follows:

unction sendEmail() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var dataRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12);
  .... etc etc as per my original post.

Suggestions? Sorry for the hand holding'ness of my post.

Comment: Did you remove var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12)?

Comment: No. It's placed just below var SS.

Comment: You need to replace var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12) with var dataRange = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 12);